# GridView DataBind() has no value in it

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I am creating an asp.net web application integrated with Facebook. I am trying to fetch the Friends of the logged in user in a grid view in my application.

Code:

```
IList<user> usrFrnds = api.Users.GetInfo(myFrndId);

Friends = usrFrnds;

// Bind to GridView to display
grvMyFriends.DataSource = Friends;
grvMyFriends.DataBind();
```

For example a user has two friends.

When Breakpoints hits

```
grvMyFriends.DataSource = Friends;
```

It shows count= 2

But when breakpoint comes to

```
grvMyFriends.DataBind();
```

then in immediate window it shows

```
Expression has been evaluated and has no value
```

I am not understanding where is the problem.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Isha

Comment: try this once, grv.DataSource = api.Users.GetInfo(myFrndId);

Comment: hi, is AutoGeneratedColumn = true form you grvMyFriends grid......check for that and remove any boundfile or template column you have in your grid

Comment: Can you plese provide me structure of you friends class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bind grid you need a list. Friend is a object not list . That's why you get this error.

Try this :

```
IList<user> usrFrnds = api.Users.GetInfo(myFrndId);

// Bind to GridView to display
grvMyFriends.DataSource = usrFrnds;
grvMyFriends.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to check if usrFrnds retrieve records.

```
   if(usrFrnds.Count > 0 )
   {
   //DATA FOUND!
   grvMyFriends.DataSource = usrFrnds.ToList(); 
   grvMyFriends.DataBind();
   }
   else
   {
    //NO DATA FOUND!
   }
```

Regards

Comment: try to add breakoint on if(usrFrnds.Count has count. To check if your IList<user> usrFrnds = api.Users.GetInfo(myFrndId); really working.

Comment: ya it is but grid view is not binding